# Setting serializers of JanusGraph server docker image

Tags: janusgraph, yq

How do I set the serializers of the JanusGraph docker image?

The following is the docker-compose.yml

```
janusgraph-service:
    container_name: janusgraph
    build: .
    restart: always
    environment:
      - JANUS_PROPS_TEMPLATE=cql-es
      - gremlinserver.graphs.ConfigurationManagementGraph=/opt/janusgraph/conf/janusgraph-cql-configurationgraph.properties
      - gremlinserver.graphManager=org.janusgraph.graphdb.management.JanusGraphManager
      - janusgraph.graph.replace-instance-if-exists=true
    depends_on:
      - cassandra-service
      - elasticsearch-service
    ports:
      - 8182:8182
```

I've tried setting it via the environment variable using
`gremlinserver.serializers[+]={ className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}` but this is causing the yaml to be invalid.

The document https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph-docker states that it uses `yq write` to update the yaml and I've experimented with yq but couldn't figure out how to write a map as a value to the key.
`yq w -P -i janusgraph-server.yaml serializers[+] { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0, config: { ioRegistries: [org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry] }}`

How can I set the gremlinserver.serializers if i'm using the JanusGraph docker image?

Edit
The expected output should look like

```
host: 0.0.0.0
port: 8182
evaluationTimeout: 30000
channelizer: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.WebSocketChannelizer
graphs:
  graph: /etc/opt/janusgraph/janusgraph.properties
scriptEngines:
  gremlin-groovy:
    plugins:
      org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.plugin.JanusGraphGremlinPlugin: {}
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.jsr223.GremlinServerGremlinPlugin: {}
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.tinkergraph.jsr223.TinkerGraphGremlinPlugin: {}
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ImportGremlinPlugin:
        classImports:
          - java.lang.Math
        methodImports:
          - java.lang.Math#*
      org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.jsr223.ScriptFileGremlinPlugin:
        files:
          - scripts/empty-sample.groovy
serializers:
  - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV3d0
    config:
      ioRegistries:
        - org.janusgraph.graphdb.tinkerpop.JanusGraphIoRegistry
processors:
  - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.session.SessionOpProcessor
    config:
      sessionTimeout: 28800000
  - className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.traversal.TraversalOpProcessor
    config:
      cacheExpirationTime: 600000
      cacheMaxSize: 1000
metrics:
  consoleReporter:
    enabled: false
    interval: 180000
  csvReporter:
    enabled: true
    interval: 180000
    fileName: /tmp/gremlin-server-metrics.csv
  jmxReporter:
    enabled: true
  slf4jReporter:
    enabled: true
    interval: 180000
  graphiteReporter:
    enabled: false
    interval: 180000
maxInitialLineLength: 4096
maxHeaderSize: 8192
maxChunkSize: 8192
maxContentLength: 65536
maxAccumulationBufferComponents: 1024
resultIterationBatchSize: 64
writeBufferLowWaterMark: 32768
writeBufferHighWaterMark: 65536
```

Comment: Can you provide the expected output?

Comment: I've updated the qns with how the relevant section of the yml should look.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused - is 'serializers' meant to be embedded somewhere in the original yaml document?

Comment: I couldn't set the serializers thru the environment variables in dokcer-compose.yml and eventually worked around it by creating a custom docker image based off Janusgraph's image and copied the already modified yaml over.